# Why does changing configureWebpack in vue.config.js to use an arrow function instead of an object break the configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have the following `vue.config.js` file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const vtkChainWebpack = require('vtk.js/Utilities/config/chainWebpack');
const packageJson = require('./package.json');

const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    public: process.env.PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
  },
  lintOnSave: false,
  publicPath: process.env.VUE_APP_STATIC_PATH,
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'itk'),
            to: 'itk',
            filter: async (resourcePath) => {
              const resourceStats = await stat(resourcePath);
              const resourceSize = resourceStats.size;
              return resourceSize <= (25 * 1024 * 1024);
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          VERSION: JSON.stringify(packageJson.version),
        },
      }),
    ],
    performance: {
      maxEntrypointSize: 4000000,
      maxAssetSize: 40000000,
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    vtkChainWebpack(config);
  },
};
```

It provides an object for `configureWebpack`. I've tried changing it to use an arrow function like so:

```js
configureWebpack: config => {
  config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
  config.plugins = [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
          {
            from: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'itk'),
            to: 'itk',
            filter: async (resourcePath) => {
              const resourceStats = await stat(resourcePath);
              const resourceSize = resourceStats.size;
              return resourceSize <= (25 * 1024 * 1024);
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          VERSION: JSON.stringify(packageJson.version),
        },
      }),
    ];
    config.performance = {
      maxEntrypointSize: 4000000,
      maxAssetSize: 40000000,
    };
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    vtkChainWebpack(config);
  },
};
```

When I run `npm run serve` (same as `vue-cli-service serve`) it starts webpack but then seems to hang indefinitely without displaying any of the usual messaging regarding bundling.

If I eventually try visiting the site it throws an error about being unable to parse a param for the favicon.ico. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your version of webpack pls

Comment: I assume you are using an old version of the `@vue/cli` because you are not using the `defineConfig` object of the last

Comment: @Sayf-Eddine - Webpack is 4.46.0, `@vue/cli` is 5.0.8, I believe I could use `defineConfig` but hadn't wanted to change more than necessary, so initially tried just changing from object to arrow function.

Comment: Can you validate my answer pls ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your problem i took your code and tried to see what was not working, first of all don't forget that `vue.config.js` is an object who will be merged into the final `webpack` config using `webpack-merge`.

So when you do `config.plugins = []` you try to override the `plugins` Array of `webpack` with his default configuration such as

`VueLoaderPlugin`
`CaseSensitivePathsPlugin` `FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin` etc...

So when you do that they don't exist anymore so the `loader` to detect the paths understand `vue` files and all of it is gone so this is why you getting an error.

Remembering you choosed to use `configureWebpack` as a function you now need to treat as i said the plugins key as an `array` and push your new plugins into it or override directly the needed plugins by searching the one needed if it doesn't fit with what you want

Example who works with your configuration:

```js
  configureWebpack: config => {
    console.log("configureWebpack", config.plugins)
    config.plugins.push(
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'process.env': {
         VERSION: JSON.stringify(packageJson.version),
       },
     }),
    )
  }
```

Or

```js
  configureWebpack: config => {
    console.log("configureWebpack", config.plugins)
    config.plugins = [
     ...config.plugins,
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'process.env': {
         VERSION: JSON.stringify(packageJson.version),
       },
     }),
    ]
  }
```

Second part of the problem and maybe i'm mistaken

In your `new CopyPlugin` it seems you are copying a plugin named `itk` what i'm guessing is equal to `vtk` ? Maybe it's a miss spelling or a typo error so when i tried to change it to this:

```js
        new CopyPlugin({
          patterns: [
            {
              from: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'vtk.js'),
              to: 'vtk',
              filter: async (resourcePath) => {
                const resourceStats = await stat(resourcePath);
                const resourceSize = resourceStats.size;
                return resourceSize <= (25 * 1024 * 1024);
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
```

It worked perfectly !

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the second bundle of code and that works! Regarding the loading of ITK, there actually are both ITK and VTK packages, so that has to stay as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions are not the same as anonymous function. Arrow function bind to the scope they are in. For most uses cases changing an anonymous function is fine and will work as expected but not always. My guess would be that either `CopyPlugin` or `DefinePlugin` is expecting something to be in scope that is not in the scope that the arrow function is bound to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions